# Issue with the character: ' (single quotation) when trying to save to mySql

Tags: php, mysql

When ever there is this character in a string I try to save: ' (single quotation) - it does not save. No error is generated. I need help to understand what is wrong. My character set must accomodate French characters. Otherwise everything works well.

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

include_once('../../../init.php');

mysql_set_charset("utf8");

$articleid  = $_POST['articleid'];
$contenu  = $_POST['editabledata'];
$name  = $_POST['name'];

mysql_query("
UPDATE al_articles SET $name='$contenu'
WHERE (ArticleID='$articleid')

") or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: You should be using PDO / MySQLi with prepared statements. The error you're getting is for exactly the same reason as why you're vulnerable to SQL injections attacks, the `'` is ending your column value prematurely since you've closed the string causing an SQL syntax error.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: you should escape single quotes. `mysql_real_escape_string($content)` will do. *Note* mysql library is deprecated and should not be used. Used PDO or mysqli which can use prepared statement

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string($content) <-- this works, thanks! I got all your comments, I will try to improve my skills!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use addslashes

```
$articleid  = addslashes($_POST['articleid']);
$contenu  = addslashes($_POST['editabledata']);
$name  = addslashes($_POST['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing is called [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) because you are using raw user input in your query.

So if you pass `Hello, my name is 'justinas'` than your query looks like `UPDATE al_articles SET $name='Hello, my name is 'justinas''`. And as you see it ruins your SQL query because if closed string.

---

**How to solve it**

Use non-deprecated library: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).
Than use prepared statement and parameters bindings:

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $_POST['name']);
$sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE al_articles SET `{$name}` = :content WHERE `ArticleID` = :id");
$sql->execute([
    ':content' => $_POST['editabledata'],
    ':id' => $_POST['articleid']
]);
```

Comment: I understand. This solution worked: mysql_real_escape_string($contenu). Your do not, It simply refuses to save. Since I am not an expert, I do not know why! But I got the point. Thank you.